# Pass cookie in OAuth2RestTemplate

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring boot 1.5.3 with Java 8. I am using Oauth2RestClient to invoke remote rest endpoint from one rest end point. The call is successful but I am unable to pass OAUTH-ACCESS-TOKEN cookie in the request. Can you please guide me as how to pass this cookie in oauth2RestTemplate.

```
    private HttpEntity<T> getHttpEntity(OAuth2RestClientDetails oAuth2RestClientDetails, T requestData) {
        HttpEntity<T> httpEntity = null;
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = getHttpHeaders(oAuth2RestClientDetails);
        if (requestData != null && httpHeaders.size() > 0) {
            httpEntity = new HttpEntity<T>(requestData, httpHeaders);
        } else if (requestData != null) {
            httpEntity = new HttpEntity<T>(requestData);
        }
        return httpEntity;
    }
```

**Problem Solved**

There was problem in below part of code:

```
private HttpEntity<T> getHttpEntity(OAuth2RestClientDetails 
  oAuth2RestClientDetails, T requestData) {
    HttpEntity<T> httpEntity = null;
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = getHttpHeaders(oAuth2RestClientDetails);
    if (requestData != null && httpHeaders.size() > 0) {
        httpEntity = new HttpEntity<T>(requestData, httpHeaders);
    } else if (requestData != null) {
        httpEntity = new HttpEntity<T>(requestData);
    }
    return httpEntity;
}
```

It was sending httpHeaders conditionally i.e. when requestData is not null and header size is greater than zero. By correcting this logic, problem is solved.

Thanks.

Comment: Problem solved. Explanation added in question.

Comment: Please post an answer below instead of defacing the question itself. Please revert the edit and post a self-answer. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is a Community Wiki answer replacing the answer having been edited into the original question [as recommended by Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267439/). The solution was posted by the asker initially.

There was a problem in the below part of the code:

```
private HttpEntity<T> getHttpEntity(OAuth2RestClientDetails 
  oAuth2RestClientDetails, T requestData) {
    HttpEntity<T> httpEntity = null;
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = getHttpHeaders(oAuth2RestClientDetails);
    if (requestData != null && httpHeaders.size() > 0) {
        httpEntity = new HttpEntity<T>(requestData, httpHeaders);
    } else if (requestData != null) {
        httpEntity = new HttpEntity<T>(requestData);
    }
    return httpEntity;
}
```

It was sending httpHeaders conditionally i.e. when requestData was not null and header size was greater than zero. By correcting this logic, the problem was solved.